# Optimizing Active directory data serialization for web-api

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, rest, active-directory

i've created an active directory api that exports data in Rest format.

While the code in itself works it is very slow, i've tried several ways to fetch the data from our active drectory but with little to no change in process speed.

In it's current form it takes almost 15 seconds per 1000 users to retrieve them and serialize their properties and then return the data.

So my question is if anyone could help me figure out how to optimize this process and reduxe the loading time. The only solution i can think of right now is to have the data stored directly in the servers RAM and use threads to update it in intervalls.

This is how it looks right now:

The class that fetches users:

```
        public List<ADUserDetail> GetUserFromGroup(String groupName)
    {

        List<ADUserDetail> userlist = new List<ADUserDetail>();
        try
        {
            var context = new PrincipalContext(
                                ContextType.Domain,
                                "domain", @"username", "password");

            using (var group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, groupName))
            {
                var users = group.GetMembers(true);
                int i = 1;

                foreach (UserPrincipal user in users)
                {
                    ADUserDetail userobj = ADUserDetail.GetProp(user);
                    Debug.WriteLine(i + " " + userobj.sAMAccountName);
                    i++;

                    userlist.Add(userobj);
                }
            }

            return userlist;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            return userlist;
        }
    }
```

So as you can tell this method grabs all users from a group and created an ADUserDetail object for each of them, ultimatly returning the list of these objects.

I've tried different methods here, using Directorysearcher but the response times have been almost identical to UserPrincipal.

The ADUserDetail Looks like this:

```
        public ADUserDetail()
    {
        _Groups = new List<string>();
    }

    public static ADUserDetail GetProp(UserPrincipal directoryUser)
    {
        return new ADUserDetail(directoryUser);
    }
    private static String GetProperty(UserPrincipal userDetail, String propertyName)
    {
        if (userDetail.GetProperty(propertyName) != null)
        {
            return userDetail.GetProperty(propertyName);
        }
        else
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
private ADUserDetail(UserPrincipal directoryUser)
    {
        String domainAddress;
        String domainName;

        _Groups = new List<string>();

        var groups = directoryUser.GetGroups();
        IEnumerable<string> groupNames = groups.Select(x => x.SamAccountName);

        foreach (string name in groupNames)
        {
            _Groups.Add(name);
        }

        _firstName = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.FIRSTNAME);
        _middleName = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.MIDDLENAME);
        _lastName = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.LASTNAME);
        _sAMAccountName = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.SAMACCOUNTNAME);
        String userPrincipalName = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.USERPRINCIPALNAME);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userPrincipalName))
        {
            domainAddress = userPrincipalName.Split('@')[1];
        }
        else
        {
            domainAddress = String.Empty;
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(domainAddress))
        {
            domainName = domainAddress.Split('.').First();
        }
        else
        {
            domainName = String.Empty;
        }
        _streetAddress = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.STREETADDRESS);
        _city = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.CITY);
        _state = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.STATE);
        _postalCode = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.POSTALCODE);
        _country = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.COUNTRY);
        _company = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.COMPANY);
        _department = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.DEPARTMENT);
        _homePhone = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.HOMEPHONE);
        _extension = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.EXTENSION);
        _mobile = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.MOBILE);
        _fax = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.FAX);
        _emailAddress = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.EMAILADDRESS);
        _title = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.TITLE);
        _manager = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.MANAGER);
        _adminDescription = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.ADMINDESCRIPTION);
        _cn = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.CONTAINERNAME);
        _company = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.COMPANY);
        _department = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.DEPARTMENT);
        _displayName = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.DISPLAYNAME);
        _distinguishedName = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.DISTINGUISHEDNAME);
        _homeDirectory = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.HOMEDIRECTORY);
        _homeDrive = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.HOMEDRIVE);
        _homeMDB = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.HOMEMDB);
        _homeMTA = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.HOMEMTA);
        _info = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.INFO);
        _mail = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.EMAILADDRESS);
        _mailNickname = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.MAILNICKNAME);
        _manager = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.MANAGER);
        _mDBUseDefaults = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.MDBUSEDEFAULTS);
        _mobile = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.MOBILE);
        _name = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.NAME);
        _neEmployeeNumber = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.NEEMPLOYEENUMBER);
        _neEdirDn = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.NEEDIRDN);
        _objectCategory = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.OBJECTCATEGORY);
        _objectClass =  "Placeholder";;
        _primaryGroupID = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.PRIMARYGROUPID);
        _proxyAddresses = "Placeholder"; ;
        _sAMAccountType = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.SAMACCOUNTTYPE);
        _showInAddressBook = "Placeholder"; ;
        _streetAddress = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.STREETADDRESS);
        _telephoneNumber = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.TELEPHONENUMBER);
        _title = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.TITLE);
        _userPrincipalName = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.USERPRINCIPALNAME);
        _employeeID = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.EMPLOYEEID);
        _c = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.COUNTRYNOTATION);
        _postalCode = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.POSTALCODE);
        _physicalDeliveryOfficeName = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.PHYSICALDELIVERYOFFICENAME);
        _instanceType = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.INSTANCETYPE);
        _whenCreated = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.WHENCREATED);
        _whenChanged = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.WHENCHANGED);
        _memberOf = "PlaceHolder";//GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.MEMBEROF);
        _directReports = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.DIRECTREPORTS);
        _userAccountControl = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.USERACCOUNTCONTROL);
        _codePage = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.CODEPAGE);
        _countryCode = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.COUNTRYCODE);
        _adminCount = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.ADMINCOUNT);
        _logonCount = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.LOGONCOUNT);
        _legacyExchangeDN = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.LEGACYEXCHANGEDN);
        _servicePrincipalName = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.SERVICEPRINCIPALNAME);
        _dSCorePropagationData = "Placeholder";
        _pager = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.PAGER);
        _homePhone = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.HOMEPHONE);
        _msExchUserAccountControl = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.MSEXCHUSERACCOUNTCONTROL);
        _msExchPoliciesIncluded = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.MSEXCHPOLICIESINCLUDED);
        _msExchRecipientDisplayType = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.MSEXCHRECIPIENTDISPLAYTYPE);

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_manager))
        {
            String[] managerArray = _manager.Split(',');
            _managerName = managerArray[0].Replace("CN=", "");
        }
    }
```

All property declarations in AdUserdetail looks like this:

```
    [DataMember]
    private String _firstName;
    [DataMember]
    private String _middleName;
    [DataMember]
    private String _lastName;
```

Followed by:

```
    public String FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
    }

    public String MiddleName
    {
        get { return _middleName; }
    }

    public String LastName
    {
        get { return _lastName; }
    }
```

All properties are declared this way and serialized using the DataMember.

The third class hinted here is the ADProperties class. It is however only a class of Constants, making it easier to keep track of propery names, it look like this:

```
    public const String ADMINDESCRIPTION = "adminDescription";
    public const String FIRSTNAME = "givenName";
    public const String MIDDLENAME = "initials";
```

and so on.

This is all then called upon by an API controller like this:

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        ActiveDirectorySearcher ADSearcher = new ActiveDirectorySearcher();

        var Users = ADSearcher.GetUserFromGroup("NameofGroup");

        if (Users != null)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Users);
        }

        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "No Users found");
    }
```

So that's how it looks, our AD is quite large with over 30k users and in some scheduled works this API is required to respond with up to 5k users, in it's current state it takes it almost 70seconds to perform this, and i want to cut that time down to below 10 seconds. But so far my attempts has been fruitless. As of right now the vast majority of the processing time happens during the serialization process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bottleneck was the lambda query at:

```
IEnumerable<string> groupNames = groups.Select(x => x.SamAccountName);
```

Replacing this cut the loading time by 10 times on most calls. The heaviest loads that previously took 132 seconds now takes 17.

I know this isnt a full answer, as i cannot tell why this lambda query was so inneficient. But it was most certainly guilty for the loading time.